# Commons VFS - Cannot list the contents of a directory

Tags: java, sftp, apache-commons-vfs

I have a problem with Commons VFS. I want to connect to a directory using SFTP and list it. Here is the code:

```
FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();

FileObject sourceDir = fsManager.resolveFile(sourceUrl, opts);
FileObject targetDir = fsManager.resolveFile(config.get("to"));

for (FileObject sourceFile : sourceDir.getChildren()) { // here is the problem
    FileObject targetFile = fsManager.resolveFile(targetDir + "/" + nodeName + "_"
            + sourceFile.getName().getBaseName());
    logger.debug("Copying files. Source: " + sourceFile.getName().getPath() + " Target: "
            + targetFile.getName().getPath());
}
```

It seems that the `fsManager` resolves it correctly but `getChildren()` fails. I found out that the `sourceDir` is an `IMAGINARY` type; the following code says it

```
logger.debug(sourceDir.getType());
```

I checked the file and it's an ordinary folder - not a link or something like that.

**Error**

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFolderException: Could not list the contents of "sftp://path/to/dir" because it is not a folder.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:693)
    at pkg.services.impl.QuartzJobEventLog.downloadEventLogs(QuartzJobEventLog.java:64)
    at pkg.services.impl.QuartzJobEventLog.executeJob(QuartzJobEventLog.java:37)
    at pkg.services.impl.AbstractQuartzJob.execute(AbstractQuartzJob.java:25)
    at $QuartzJob_1360635dbcd.execute($QuartzJob_1360635dbcd.java)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html) getting "directory contents" is not supported for the SFTP filesystem.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on which version of VFS solution will be different. For VFS 2.0 you have to include additional config option below.

```
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance( ).setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem here. Your solution is for situations when you want (especially on unix) access an absolute path.

Comment: I had this exact problem, and setting this config option worked for me. I can now list directory contents via sftp. Apache documentation site is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem when we upgraded the VFS version 1.0 to 2.1 and found that documentation gives to right direction as we need to set below flag to avoid using relative path from user's home directory.

*By default, the path is relative to the user's home directory. This can be changed with:*

```
FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(options, false);
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP

Answer (score 0):

I was working with FTP and not SFTP protocol but encounterd the same problem as Tomas described. What helped was enabling passive mode

```
FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(opts, true);
```